# Not able to connect my wordpress instance in public subnet to the MySQL database instance in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am doing a project in which My WordPress resides in an EC2 instance, which sits in a public subnet and has a route to an Internet gateway. And a MySQL database which is set up in an EC2 instance in the private subnet. I have configured everything. Allow inbound to port 3306 from the security group of WordPress and, 3306 port in outbound of WordPress INstance with SG of MySQL (though it's not necessary).

I set up my SQL database and created a user, database, and password for my WordPress. And also installed a MySQL client in the WordPress instance.

But in the end when I tried to connect the MySQL database from wordpress instance it is not connecting, it is saying that the host I am trying to reach is unable to connect.

```
sudo MySQL -h <privat_ip address of MySQL instance> -u wordpressuser -p
```

And I have configured the NAT GATEWAY as well in the public subnet, I think I have tried every known solution but it is not connecting.